# Optimizing an Ajax based website for Google Search

Tags: ajax, search, seo, search-engine

I would really like to hear your opinions about search engine optimizations for an Ajax based website.

The study case is the following:

http://projects.trapexit.org/

What are your SEO hints for such an application?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rule of thumb is that search engines see what Lynx sees, and Lynx doesn't see a list of software projects.  Thus, this page should add a non-AJAX interface (using `<noscript>`?), perhaps with reduced functionality but with all the information there.

Comment: Hi! Just a question about that: if this is true, what if e.g. I build my site so that it does work without JavaScript, BUT when JS is enabled, I bind menu links' click event to AJAX calls that load the site's appropriate part (for example with the help of jQuery), which means the site doesn't need to completely refresh all the time, and is a more user friendly solution?

In theory - if I'm not wrong - it would mean the site could be indexed by search engines and can be user friendly too.

I plan to do these changes on my sites, but tell me if anything is wrong in my conception.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build)

Comment: +1 However, as most people would argue, its probably best to avoid overusing AJAX when SEO matters to your application.

Comment: Yes. But the application is not mine. Usually it happens that you have a legacy system or something created by someone else and you need to work on that anyway.

Comment: Then retrofit it so it looks as if it was built on things that work. There is no getting away from the fact that "working cleanly without JavaScript" is the only sane way to deal with search engines.

Answer (score 0):

If a search bot has to execute an event in order to get code from a server and then know where and how the DOM has changed then I would say to merely write accessible code.  However, a search bot cannot do any of those things and AJAX defeats accessibility, so you can improve SEO dramatically by forgetting AJAX or instead forgetting SEO.